# Is Kernel Density Estimation actually the continuous/curved version of a histogram?

Tags: machine-learning, python, arima

I have been studying ARIMA for a bit of time now, and stumbled upon the [*plot_diagnostics*](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.plot_diagnostics.html) function.

Among others, it plots out the Histogram & KDE on the same plot. As I did not know anything about KDE, I looked it up, and from my understanding, it is basically a histogram with very very small interval lengths (assuming the data would be continuous so a histogram with such small interval lengths makes sense). Am I right, or am I missing something?

Thank you!